# Active logins change in who -a and who

Tags: ssh, login

```
system boot  2019-06-13 19:14
           run-level 5  2019-06-13 19:14
LOGIN      tty2         2019-06-13 19:14               420 id=tty2
LOGIN      console      2019-06-13 19:14               419 id=cons
           pts/0        2019-06-13 19:23               909 id=ts/0  term=0 exit=0
user + pts/1        2019-06-20 23:21 00:07         934 (177.232.6.247 via mosh [934])
user + pts/2        2019-06-20 23:27   .         21805 (177.232.6.247)
           pts/3        2019-06-19 11:03              2313 id=ts/3  term=0 exit=0
           pts/4        2019-06-13 20:14              2184 id=ts/4  

term=0 

exit=0
```

what is going on with pts/0, pts/3 and pts/4. Are they active logins? there appear to be no users there, although who just returns:

```
user pts/1        2019-06-20 23:21 (177.232.6.247 via mosh [934])
user pts/2        2019-06-20 23:43 (177.232.6.247)
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally `who` without any additional flags only prints information about 
users who are currently logged in.

`who -a` includes *almost* **all** `who` options including the `-d` option to also print dead processes.

These are the dead processes (and not active logins):

```
       pts/0        2019-06-13 19:23               909 id=ts/0  term=0 exit=0
       pts/3        2019-06-19 11:03              2313 id=ts/3  term=0 exit=0
       pts/4        2019-06-13 20:14              2184 id=ts/4  term=0 exit=0
```

The recorded exit status from `who -d` can provide info if the process exited cleanly (`exit=0`) or not.

With for instance `last pts/0` you can see which user has used that pseudo terminal last.